# list::remove_if equivalent

Tags: c++, list, remove-if

I'd like to know if its possible to represent this expression using remove_if and a lambda expression.

```
        std::list< gh::Actor* >::iterator astit = actors.begin();
        while (astit != actors.end())
        {           
            if( (*astit)->state == DELETE_STATE )
            {           
                Actor* reference = *astit;
                actors.erase(astit++);

                delete reference;
            }
            else
            {
                ++astit;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Does this work? http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/remove

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
actors.erase(
  std::remove_if( actors.begin(), actors.end(), []( gh::Actor*a )->bool {
    if (!a || a->state == DELETE_STATE) {
      delete a;
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }),
  actors.end()
);
```

As an aside, you almost certainly do not want to use `std::list`.  Use `std::vector` -- the cases where `std::list` outperforms `std::vector` are exceedingly narrow.

Answer (score 2):

Better use `smart pointers` with `lambda`.

Try:

```
std::list<std::shared_ptr<gh::Actor>> actors;
actors.remove_if([](std::shared_ptr<Actor>& a){ return a->state == DELETE_STATE; });
```